# p2p - Send data from Windows Computer to RPI

Tags: wireless, communication, p2p

I want to be able to send a small amount of data quickly directly from a windows machine to a Raspberry Pi 3 B+.

My restrictions include:

- Preferably not having any sort of wired connection between the two devices.
- The nature of the problem involves having both devices being on the move and connected to a guest network that I have no control over.
- If necessary, I am fine with using some third party API or service such that will help me solve this problem.

What's the best and simplest way to do this?

Comment: check out MQTT ..... https://shiftr.io/shiftr-io/demo

Comment: @jsotola You should post that as an answer and I'll mark it correct. I didn't even know that existed, thanks for the help!

Comment: MQTT is not P2P, so your question seems to disqualify the answer you have accepted. More importantly, your question is problematic because whatever data transfer protocol is best is a matter of opinion. Any suggestion to check out XMPP, HTTP and other XXXP and XXP abbreviation is a valid answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a MQTT broker to relay the messages.

There are a number of brokers available on the web.

This one is very good for developing your code because of the visual feedback.

https://shiftr.io/try

https://shiftr.io/shiftr-io/demo